# ZF2 - Error messages failing to display

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using ZF2 with doctrine ORM and every so often error reporting fails and I get meaningless errors:

http://screencast.com/t/UgZMb89vZ

When it works correctly, errors look like:

http://screencast.com/t/RlOEZxuGUsfu

To bug test this I have run git bisect and have checked every change made between the time when proper errors are reported and when they fail.

Nothing obvious shows up.

My only solution to fixing this problem is to roll back to a version where error reporting is working and to re-add my changes.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue to this?

Comment: check `display_exceptions` in `view_manager` config. set it to `true` if you don't have it.also check `exception_template` in `view_manager` config, and check the template file to see if there is any error inside it.

Comment: Thanks, I did all those checks.

Comment: Do you have any try-catch statement which catches your exceptions and does a redirect to 404 error page?

Comment: In most cases I do. I am going to have to wait for it to revert to the issue again before I can re-test. Something somewhere is being changed, just not certain what. Definitely not my code - when I roll back I copy all my modules and then overwrite the revert with my latest work and it works fine. Very odd.